# Check if time falls in weekends

Tags: go

I have a custom weekend time which is from `Friday 10pm UTC` to `Sunday 10:05pm UTC`. I have a current timestamp in UTC and just wanted to check if the time falls in weekend time. Any tricks will be much appreciated. I tried using `weekdays() and time` but was not able to achieve the desired results.

Comment: "I tried using `weekdays() and`..." - show us what you tried then and we can suggest improvements...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> check if the time falls in weekend time which is from Friday 10pm UTC to Sunday 10:05pm UTC.

---

Use the Go [`time`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/)  package.

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

// A weekend is Friday 10pm UTC to Sunday 10:05pm UTC
func isWeekend(t time.Time) bool {
    t = t.UTC()
    switch t.Weekday() {
    case time.Friday:
        h, _, _ := t.Clock()
        if h >= 12+10 {
            return true
        }
    case time.Saturday:
        return true
    case time.Sunday:
        h, m, _ := t.Clock()
        if h < 12+10 {
            return true
        }
        if h == 12+10 && m <= 5 {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

func main() {
    t := time.Date(2019, 11, 22, 12+10, 5, 0, 0, time.UTC)
    fmt.Println(t)
    w := isWeekend(t)
    fmt.Println(w)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/TZBoNcwH-qU

Output:

```
2019-11-22 22:05:00 +0000 UTC
true
```